# How to identify cases that have multiple variables with the same value in SPSS

Tags: spss

I have a dataset in which there are multiple variables for various times.
Here is a sample part of the dataset:
[image]
 I'm trying to identify the number/percentage of cases that have the same value in any of the multiple variables.

For example, if I have a database of teachers who left a school where they worked and there are variables for why the teacher left each school, how would I find out if a teacher left multiple schools for the same reason. So I have reasonleft1, reasonleft2, reasonleft3, up to 20. Each reasonleft has the same coded response options. For example, 1=better opportunity elsewhere, 2=retired, 3=otherwise left workforce, etc. I'm stumped on how to figure out if any case/teacher left multiple schools for the same reason. Which teachers left multiple schools out of the 20 for 1=better opportunity elsewhere, for example.

Thanks!

Comment: This should be easy enough by a little restructure and aggregation (aggregation by teacher and reason will give you a count for each reason within teacher). If you add a table with a sample of the data (so we can see the actual data structure), and also the expected results for the sample, We'll be able to help you with actual code.

Comment: Thank you! I've done the table and aggregation, but I need to know on a case level. How many individual cases have the same response to two or more "reasonleft". Does that make sense?

Comment: Please edit your post with sample data and expected results, this will make it easier to understand what you need so I can help you

Comment: Tried pasting a screen shot, but didn't work so I'll try to describe. The rows are individual cases, each with unique ID. The columns that are important are ID, facilitytype1, reasonleft1, facilitytype2, reasonleft2, facilitytype3,reasonleft3, all the way to facilitytype20, reasonleft20. The facility type has values of 1-3 and the reasonleft has values of 1-10. I can do the tables showing me the numbers and percentages of each individual column, but I what I need to know is which cases/how many cases has a reasonleft value of 5 more than once. % of pop who has left for 5 reason more than once.

Comment: I think I added the photo to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in the following two steps:

1. You need to restructure the dataset so that each "time" appears in a separate row.
2. Now you can aggregate to count the number of appearances of each reason per person.

The following syntax will do that:

```
varstocases  
     /make facilititype from facilititype1_pre facilititype2_pre facilititype3_pre   
     /make timeinplace from timeinplace1_pre timeinplace2_pre timeinplace3_pre  
     /make reasonleft from reasonleft1_pre reasonleft2_pre reasonleft3_pre  
     /index = timeN(reasonleft).
* you should continue the numbering for as much as needed.

dataset declare MyAgg.  
aggregate outfile=MyAgg /break=ID reasonleft/Ntimes=n.
```

At this point you have a new dataset which has the count of each reason for each ID. If you wish you can go back to wide format, and create a column for each reason (the values in each column are the count of times this reason appeared for the ID).
This way:

```
dataset activate MyAgg.
casestovars /id=ID /index=reasonleft/separator="_".
```

Comment: I think I got it. Maybe. :-) Thank you!